# How to not select same item on listbox which is selected before

Tags: c#

Currently im trying to make a mp3 player. I have a checkbox which is called 'play songs randomly'. And a listbox full of songs. My question is that i dont want to play same song if its selected once. How do i do this?
i am using the following code:

```
Random rnd = new Random()
    private void btnnext_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            int number = rnd.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count - 1);
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = number;
            play();
        }
```

And one last thing: i can't select the last index of listbox if checkbox is checked. it never selects last index. how can i fix this?

Comment: winforms? asp.net? etc?

Comment: Pick them from a separate private `List<T>`, and each time you pick one, remove it from that list. Simple.

Comment: `int number = rnd.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);`

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention it. its winforms

Comment: I think you might have to add a foreach on the listBox1 and grab the Checked checkboxes into a new list, and send the new list to play. In the new list, you would probably check to see if your random sampling generated duplicates and remove them from the new list before sending it to play.

Comment: Generate a list of indexes, shuffle them, and then play tracks based on those indexes

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to take all the song indexes (0 -> song.Count - 1), shuffle them, and then play the songs in that order.

For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Pretend this is your list of songs
    var orderedListOfSongs = new List<string>
    {
        "song one",
        "song two",
        "song three",
        "song four",
        "song five",
        "song six",
        "song seven",
        "song eight",
        "song nine",
        "song ten",
    };

    // Generate a new list of ints representing the index of each song and shuffle them
    // Note: There are better ways to shuffle a list, this is just for an example
    var rnd = new Random();
    var randomizedIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, orderedListOfSongs.Count)
        .OrderBy(i => rnd.NextDouble())
        .ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < orderedListOfSongs.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Now playing: {orderedListOfSongs[randomizedIndexes[i]]}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]